# Ionic/Cordova - AJAX requests failing with status code of -1

Tags: android, ios, ajax, cordova

I am unable to get my AJAX requests working on an Ionic + Cordova app deployed to iOS and Android. I get the following rejection:

`{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"auth":true,"url":"http://myapp/api/users/me","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer 00D17000000BUvD!ARcAQKWePqxMuG2PAGxSfgas48nWGAkP7THZir6j5nzgodOR.xGZyXzVh9z5CvxaYe6hO.aKwH.gqvZCGL6a2QW74lBIrEtR"}},"statusText":""}`

This request works as expected on the web app and in Postman.

I have added the following to my root config.xml file, ran "ionic prepare" and verified they are in the platforms/ios/MyApp/config.xml. (Note: Where should I check for Android?):

`<access origin="*" />
 <allow-navigation href="*" />`

I have installed "cordova-plugin-whitelist" and it is in both plugins/android.json and plugins/ios.json, but I'm not sure where I can verify these are included as expected.

AJAX requests worked until I installed `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` and ran `ionic prepare` - I think this wiped out some misplaced XML config that made it work. Also, I do see in my logs that the request appears to have hit my API. Perhaps there is a different issue here?

Answer (score 1):

cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine turned out to be the culprit. I tried to remove it, but I must not have fully removed it on my first try. Removing cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine got everything working again.

Comment: Having the same issue here. So is removing this plugin the only solution? cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine seems to improve IOS performance by A LOT..