# Ionic POST fails with status code -1 when testing on device?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic v1. I have configured my wamp server to listen for `8100` port and `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`.

I can post to server when testing in browser using i`onic serve` but when testing on device request fails with status code -1 and no message.

```
Object {data: null, status: -1, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: ""}
config: Object
data: null
headers: function (name) {
status: -1
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124793/ionic-cordova-ajax-requests-failing-with-status-code-of-1) which suggests to remove `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`. However this plugin is not present in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a CORS issue, you should get a CORS error in the console when you run the app in the browser with `ionic serve`. If that's that case, try setting up a proxy in the Ionic CLI. Details here: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/